# Como fazer com que uma função HTML pare de funcionar com o JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

Eu gostaria que, caso o `allowSubmit` seja falso, ele não executasse o *action* do `form` (`action="logintest.php"`).
Como posso fazer isso?

```
function check_if_capcha_is_filled (e) {
    if(allowSubmit)
        return true;
    else{
        alert('Fill in the capcha!');
        //Código aqui
    }
}

<form method="post" onsubmit="check_if_capcha_is_filled()" action="logintest.php">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function check_if_capcha_is_filled (e) {
    if(allowSubmit)
        return true;
    else{
        alert('Fill in the capcha!');
        return false;
    }
}
<form method="post" onsubmit="return check_if_capcha_is_filled()" action="logintest.php">
```

Só colocar o return no onsubmit e retornar false.